# How to draw a trapezoid shape line in flutter using Rrect or similar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-custompainter, custom-painter

I want to draw a trapezoidal shape in flutter, like this:

[image]

Now I am drawing an elliptical shape using Rrect for the same,

[image]

here is my code for drawing the second picture(getting an elliptical shape)

```
 @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Offset circleOffset =
        offset + Offset(cfg.size!.width / 2, cfg.size!.height + 8);
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromCenter(center: circleOffset, width: 50, height: 5),
          Radius.circular(radius),
        ),
        _paint);
  }
```

Comment: check all `RRect.fromRect*` constructors

Comment: you only want to achieve this with paint? @AbdulazeezVP

Comment: @eamirho3ein Yes, please suggest other options as well. I'd like to see that shape line in the bottom navigation bar tab.

Comment: @pskink I tried a few, not able to figure it out properly.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/RRect/RRect.fromRectAndCorners.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Rrect.fromRectAndCorners,

```
  {
    Radius topLeft = Radius.circular(10),
    ///top left corner curve or radius, in my case it is 10
    Radius topRight = Radius.circular(10),
    ///top right corner curve or radius, in my case it is 10
    Radius bottomRight = Radius.zero,
    ///bottom left corner curve or radius, in my case it is zero
    Radius bottomLeft = Radius.zero
    ///bottom right corner curve or radius, in my case it is zero
  }
```

so my final code looks like

```
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
    final Offset circleOffset =
        offset + Offset(cfg.size!.width / 2, cfg.size!.height + 8);
    canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: circleOffset, width: 50, height: 5),
        bottomLeft: Radius.zero,
        bottomRight: Radius.zero,
        topLeft: Radius.circular(radius),
        topRight: Radius.circular(radius),
      ),
      _paint,
    );
  }
```

will get more details in the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/RRect/RRect.fromRectAndCorners.html)

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/RRect/RRect.fromRectAndCorners.html

Thanks for help.